# simple question in sentence with a prepostion

Tags: sentence-construction

> I want to use a pencil to drawing a picture.

is it a correct sentence?

If not, please, change it into a right sentence.

I want native speakers what to think about the sentence.

Comment: I need a pencil to draw a/the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is

> I want to use a pencil to draw a picture.

The addition of does not change the verb form

> I want to draw a picture.

However, neither of these are questions.

A question related to the original sentence might be:

> Do you want to use a pencil to draw a picture?

The form "drawing" could be used in such sentences as:

> - I am drawing a picture.
> - I saw him drawing a picture.
> - I saw him drawing a picture with a pencil.